# Smarty - Fill a table with Arrays

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table, smarty

In my PHP class I'm sending over some arrays, for every contract the customer has a row in the table should be filled. 
I got some mistakes with my date:

> on line 70 "{$date[$id] | date_format: %d %m %Y}"  - Unexpected "|"

also some errors for the other arrays

```
<table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Datum</td>
                <td>Preis</td>
                <td>Verbrauch</td>
                <td>Abnahmestellen</td>
                <td>Status</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            {foreach from=$contractCount item=item  key=key}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{System::getLink('contractView')}"><input type="button" style="text-align: center" width="200em"  value="Gehe zu "></a>{$id+1}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {$date[$id] | date_format: %d %m %Y}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {$KWhRate[$id]}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {$totalUsage[$id]}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {$consumptionsPoints[$id]}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {if $status[$id] == 0}
                            <span {literal}style="background-color:#ff9933"{/literal}>In Bearbeitung</span>
                        {/if}
                        {if $item->status[$id] == 1}
                            <span  {literal}style="background-color:#ff0000"{/literal}>Abgeschlossen</span>
                        {/if}
                        {if $item->status[$id] == 2}
                            <span {literal}style="background-color:#33cc33"{/literal}>Stoniert</span>
                        {/if}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {/foreach}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: how do you set `$id` variable ? from controller or via smarty ?

Comment: and what's the other errors ?

Comment: $id = 0 ... its in the php code , its says that arrays are not allowed there

Comment: what is the error phrase ?

Comment: Cannot use object of type data\OfferResult as array in

Comment: in which line!?!

Comment: in the lane of $KWhRate

Comment: you need to send this `$KWhRate` from your controller as an array , check it out from the controller